# blur a div with image

Tags: jquery, css

I have html structure

```
<div class="div">
<img src="img1.jpg" class="img" />
</div>
```

How do I make `div` appear blurred without removing image ?

Comment: @Harry could you please write an answer?

Comment: http://markos.gaivo.net/examples/canvas_blur/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not really a blur, but transparency.

http://www.w3schools.com/Css/css_image_transparency.asp

add something like this to your css file :

```
div.div img.img {
   opacity:0.4;filter:alpha(opacity=40)
}
```

I think it's the only solution you'll find without using some javascript or dirty css3 hacks like http://simurai.com/post/716453142/css3-image-blur for example.

Comment: @experimentX : this is what I'm suggesting to do.

Comment: @Harry Joy sure it was helpful, and using it now, would you care to vote up the other guy'a answer, that was informative too

Comment: thanks for the accepting ;) Already voted up the other answer which is a good one provided you can use javascript.

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure you can blur images with pure css. Please correct me if I'm wrong.

My tip would be to try a jquery solution.

A good one is:
http://www.pixastic.com/lib/docs/actions/blur/

Comment: There's some solution with CSS3, but they are hacks. For example you can put many copies of the same image, slightly moved to each side with different transparency. I strongly advised against this kind of tricks ;)

Comment: That's what I meant, it's hard with the cross browser compatibility as well.